# MS DOS: how to unattendedly write specific byte on specific address on HDD, e.g.: write(000F3,FF)

Tags: hard-drive, ms-dos

How can I perform direct, low level writing to the hard drive under MS DOS in an unattended way? Specifically, I need to write to bytes on the MBR, but at the byte level, so FDISK, RPM, etc. won't do.
Does anybody know any tool?
Thanks!

Comment: Software recommendation questions are off-topic, but any good disk editor will do. Just search the net.

Comment: Thanks Karan. Nevertheless if I asked here is because I already searched the net to no avail.

Comment: We can't answer your question since it isn't on topic.  I did a Google search and found 10 programs that would do this on the first result page...

Comment: Norton Disk Doctor comes to mind... though I'd say it would be much easier to find Linux tools for the same.

Comment: I would use a hex editor for that.

Comment: @M.Suscripto: Surely you're not trying to say that searching for "disk editor" returned *no* results at all for you? If you found nothing then you used the wrong search terms.

Comment: @Karan: I wasn't looking for an ordinary editor, I needed something scriptable, automatic. You're right, I wasn't clear on this point.

Comment: @M.Suscripto: Ah, wish you'd said that in the first place. Anyway your query has been answered but FWIW there are disk/hex editors out there that can run user-defined scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using some kind of disk editor as suggested by @Karan, but...

If you want to do it really hard-core badass way and use only what is included with the DOS itself then you should look at `debug` command.

[Debug: W (Write)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722863.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#XSLTsection141121120120)

Be very careful because even slightest mistake will be disastrous.

I can not give detailed instructions right now because I have not touched MS-DOS machine for at least 10 years and particular functionality for maybe 20 years and I don't have a machine to test it at hand but linked reference should give enough pointers to achieve what you want.

Basically, you read sector from disk, edit and write it back to disk.

Googling brought up this: [A Guide to DEBUG](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/debug.htm)

It tells that you actually can not use `debug` to modify MBR directly but later describes how to do it.

Comment: Ahh, this brings back memories of using `debug` to edit simcity save games to give myself millions of dollars ;)

Comment: Thank you Andres, that's the kind of answer I was looking for. Some policenerds around here got too nervous on my question so I just edited to basically ask the same thing using different words: insted of "which program" I now use "how can I", Am I not a great potential politician?

Comment: But can it  be done in an unattended way ?

Comment: @Wishwas "A Guide to DEBUG" I linked shows how to run `debug` scripted. That is as unattended as it gets.